# Testing reactjs components with mochajs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, redux, mocha.js

I'm trying to run a simple test with `mochajs`:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    ActionCreators = require('../src/components/Dashboard/ActionCreators.js');

describe('', function () {
  it('', function () {
    assert.equal(1, 1);
  });
});
```

But it throws errors that the `ActionCreators` file contain `import` keywords. It does, becuase I run my code with webpack, and it goes through babel.

I've been trying to run this test with `mocha-webpack`, but it's the same. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use mocha command line option `--compilers js:babel-core/register`. Of course you have to have `babel-core` npm package installed.